IPC 2221 - Clearance for buck Converter switching node?
For the design of a buck converter which is the minimum clearance I have to comply for the switching node? Do I need to look at the maximum voltage of the switching node and from there use IPC 222-1?

Depends on your voltage. What's your maximum input voltage?
